# What is react-native-cli and @react-native-community/cli?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I am confusing about react-native-cli and @react-native-community/cli.
Right now, I am using react-native-cli to generate new project.

Then I want to try react native using typescript. In the documentation, they said to "Remove react native cli" and install @react-native-community/cli.

After doing that, I can generate my react native project using typescript. But now, I cant run my old react native project, because I remove the react-native-cli.

What should I do?

Comment: If you're using the cli packages globally to run your projects, just keep them both installed.

Comment: On second thought, you might not be able to because they probably use the same cli command name. In that case, install them as dev dependencies in your projects and have your npm scripts refer to the local versions.

Comment: Thanks for you response.
I finally got a solution, 
First, uninstall the react-native-cli.
Second, install @react-native-community/cli.
Third, with I can create react native init with typescript template.
For old project, I should run it using npx react-native start then npx react-native run-ios / npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove react-native-cli

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli
```

Second, install @react-native-community/cli

```
npm i -g @react-native-community/cli
```

Third, with this I should able to create react native project using typescript tempalate

```
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript
```

Fourth, for run existing project or old react native project

```
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-android / npx react-native run-ios
```

Source
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript/issues/72

Comment: Hi @Ganda is there any command that launches both Metro and run-android as it happens in Windows when you do npx react-native run-android ? In Linux I have to run react-native start or npm start then run-android